# Loop elements by order of Data attributes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Suppose I have HTML elements like below

```
<span class="active" data-id="3"> Test 3 </span>
<span class="active" data-id="1"> Test 1 </span>
<span class="active" data-id="2"> Test 2 </span>


$(".active"].each(function(index,item){
var val = $(item).data("id");
console.log(val);
});
```

This will output

```
3
1
2
```

Is there anyway we can sort this loop based on data attribute and get the elements by the order or Data attribute or some other way so it will output

```
1
2
3
```

Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate of [Sorting a list by data-attribute](/q/32199368/4642212). Just replace the sort function by `({dataset: {id: a}}, {dataset: {id: b}}) => Number(a) - Number(b)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the ´sort´ higher order array method. [Sort MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```
const elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-id]'))

const sorted = elements.sort((firstEle, secondEle) => {
    const firstId = firstEle.dataset.id
    const secondId = secondEle.dataset.id
    
    return firstId > secondId
})


console.log(sorted)
```